# Why my CSS not working in my Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

Hey i got a problem with my app.css, he dont render in my page and i dont understand why, when my friend try it with his own PC that's work.

When i use the yarn encore dev to compile , i dont have problem, in my console too there is no problem.
Im pretty new to Symfony , so maybe i missed something
There is my ***html.twig***

```html
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class=" text-center text-white bg-dark">
    <!-- Grid container -->
    <div class="container p-4">

        <!-- Section: Text -->
        <section class="mb-1">
            <a href="{{ path('home') }}" class="footerLinks"><img src="/img/home/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"/></a>
        </section>
        <!-- Section: Text -->
        <section class="text-center p-1">
        <a href="#!" class="text-white p-2 footerLinks">Qui sommes nous</a>
        <a href="#!" class="text-white p-2 footerLinks">Contact</a>
        <a href="#!" class="text-white p-2 footerLinks">Concept</a>
        </section>

    </div>
    <!-- Grid container -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
                        <p>© 2020 Copyright: Mehdi, Kélian, Messine, Nejma.<p>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
```

And My ***Webpack.config***

```php
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/img',
    //optional target path, relative to the output dir
        to: '../img/[path][name].[ext]',
    /*
    // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    // only copy files matching this pattern //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
    */
    })

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('authentication', './assets/authentication.js')
    .addEntry('home', './assets/home.js')
    .addEntry('catalogue', './assets/catalogue.js')
    .addEntry('profile', './assets/profile.js')
    .addEntry('admin_show_films', './assets/admin_show_films.js')
    .addEntry('admin_show_users', './assets/admin_show_users.js')
    .addEntry('film_show_one', './assets/film_show_one.js')

    
    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    //Ajout de VueJs
    .enableVueLoader()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: app.css isn't and added entry in your code. Are you adding it in JS?

Comment: Yep i import it :
import './styles/app.css';

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the provided code you probably forgot the entry tags in your base-template ?

```
{% block stylesheets %}

      {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}

 {% endblock %}

 {% block javascripts %}

      {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
 
 {% endblock %}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html